# How to return selected value from "select" html tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a basic version of Twitter, with Rails.I am having some issues with the "select" html tag. I have the following code:

```
<div class="field">
<select name="user_id">
  <% users = User.all %>
    <% users.each do |i| %>
    <option value=i.id> <%= i.name %> </option>
  <% end %>
</select>
</div>
```

Currently the "select" tag is returning NIL. I need it to return the ID from user.id. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby On Rails provides useful helpers to write html, check it out the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease).

For a select you can use the `select_tag` helper.

Something like this if you have to deal with the `User` model:

```
<% users_array = User.all.map { |u| [u.name, u.id] } %>
<%= options_for_select(users_array) %>
```

or in one single line:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I try with this code :                                                 <% users_array = User.all.map { |u| [u.name, u.id] } %>
<%= select_tag(:user_id, options_for_select(users_array)) %>             This results of a list with all my users, but still, "user_id" contains NIL again, after validation. Is something wrong with my code ?